# Disable sticky posts feature

Tags: wp-admin, sticky-post

I need to create a custom WordPress admin interface for a client. I want to completely disable the sticky post feature from admin area.

I found some posts on the internet that suggest to hide the checkbox using css, but I would really like to disable that feature both from edit and from quick edit screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to CSS you could try to unstick each post as soon as it has been made sticky (untested):

```
add_action( 'post_stuck', function( $post_id )
{
    unstick_post( $post_id );
} );
```

If you're looking for another approach, than hiding it from the UI with CSS, then consider using **custom post types** instead of the `post` post type.

As far as I remember the *sticky* UI feature is only supported by the `post` post type. At least a quick look at the posts list table class, shows a check like this one:

```
if ( 'post' === $post_type && $sticky_posts = get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) {
```

But not using the `post` post type, might not be suitable in many cases, and it might need further adjustments for your site.

Answer (score 0):

you could add this code:

```
// Hide sticky posts
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'hide_sticky_option' );
function hide_sticky_option() {
global $post_type, $pagenow;
if( 'post.php' != $pagenow && 'post-new.php' != $pagenow && 'edit.php' != $pagenow )
    return;
?>
<style type="text/css">#sticky-span { display:none!important }
.quick-edit-row .inline-edit-col-right div.inline-edit-col > :last-child > label.alignleft:last-child{ display:none!important; }</style>
<?php
}
```

This works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

The best and most optimal solution is to simply "ignore" sticky posts on all queries which can be done with this code:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', 1 );
    }
} );
```

Of course the user can still click the checkbox but it won't actually do anything so it won't matter. But here is a good article showing how to hide with CSS if wanted - [Is there a way to disable the sticky posts feature?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10676/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-sticky-posts-feature)